# Angular app error

Tags: angularjs

Below is my app.js

```
   var appAcademia = angular.module("appAcademia", ['ui.router', 'ngResource' ,'localStorageModule']); 
 appAcademia.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, resourceProvider,$httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/Home/Home',
      controller: 'HomeController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
  })
 .state('about', {
     // we'll get to this in a bit       
 });
 });
 var authServiceBase = 'http://localhost:12019/';
 var resourceServiceBase = 'http://localhost:12007/'; 

 appAcademia.constant('ngAuthSettings', {
apiAuthServiceBaseUri: authServiceBase,
apiResourceServiceBaseUri: resourceServiceBase,
clientId: '414e1927a3884f68abc79f7283837fd1'
});  appAcademia.run(['authService', function (authService) {
authService.fillAuthData();
}]);
```

and here is a part of my view or index page

```
<body class="preview" id="top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".subnav" data-offset="80" data-ng-app="appAcademia">
```

and here is the error I am getting.

```
  Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'App' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Now my module name is appAcademia. So how on earth I'm getting the above error? Where is the module 'App' coming from?
Now here comes the most bizarre part.

```
 Module "appAcademia" was created but never loaded.
```

let me add that all the dependent modules were created but never loaded

Comment: put ng-app="appAcademia" in your view

Comment: @ Ashish Kumawat   here is a part of the view that contains the ng-app="appAcademia"   <body class="preview" id="top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".subnav" data-offset="80" data-ng-app="appAcademia">

Comment: Can you post the HTML code?

Comment: I think your template url is not proper please check it. @Julius Tetteh

Comment: @ Shaohao Lin  This is about how much I can post via the comment box or i will have to wait for 90 minutes to post a full code<body class="preview" id="top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".subnav" data-offset="80" data-ng-app="appAcademia"> <div> @RenderBody()</div>
 </body>

Comment: Could you put your code on plunker or jsFidle.

Comment: @ Ashish Kumawat Havent tried that before. Give me a couple of minutes to get to it

Comment: And i want to inform you that don't use space between @ and username. This is will not let user give any message.

Comment: @Ashish Kumawat Not so sure if I understand what you mean by "template url"

Comment: @ Ashish Kumawat Oh ok. Hmmmmm!!! It coul be. But you see, I am using mvc action methods to load the views....... Yeah I might just be getting it wrong here. Let me do some work around and see what happens. It has worked for me previously though

Comment: @ Ashish Kumawat The template url is not the problem

Comment: @ Ashish Kumawat I just noticed something. For the home page to load ui-router has to created and loaded that is how the home page which i changed to welcome page gets loaded. ("Home/Welcome"). From here some how the module(s) get off loaded. Well I really dont know. Please help me out here

Comment: I am confused man, with code it will be better to understand.

Comment: @Ashish Kumawat var appAcademia = angular.module("appAcademia", ['ui.router', 'ngResource' ,'localStorageModule']);

appAcademia.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,  $resourceProvider,$httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
          url: '/home',
          templateUrl: '/Home/Welcome',
          controller: 'HomeController',
          controllerAs: 'vm',
      })
     .state('about', {
         // we'll get to this in a bit       
     });

Comment: @Ashish Kumawat Got rid of the initial problem I complained about. Now I am saddled with another one and it almost the same only this time the reference is to my actual module and not some non existent module. I am trying to see if I can get it into  jsFiddle or plunker. Got to tell you this, I am not enjoying angular at all. Too many bolts, nuts and screws

Comment: YEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! IGOT IT FINALLY!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!